# Why does CanvasGradient require a CanvasRenderingContext2D to create it?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, render, linear-gradients

HTML's Canvas 2D drawing with CanvasRenderingContext2D allows setting fillStyle to be a CanvasGradient like so:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,200,0);
gradient.addColorStop(0,"green");
gradient.addColorStop(1,"white");
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fillRect(10,10,200,100);
```

Where the context the gradient was created on and used on are the same; however, this doesn't have to be case since this also works:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,200,0);
gradient.addColorStop(0,"green");
gradient.addColorStop(1,"white");

var renderCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");
renderCtx.fillStyle = gradient;
renderCtx.fillRect(10,10,200,100);
```

And even more surprisingly, the canvas that the gradient was part of doesn't have to be the same or even displayed:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

var gradientCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = gradientCanvas.getContext("2d");

var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,200,0);
gradient.addColorStop(0,"green");
gradient.addColorStop(1,"white");

var renderCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");
renderCtx.fillStyle = gradient;
renderCtx.fillRect(10,10,200,100);
```

This means that it doesn't matter which CanvasRenderingContext2D it's created from (unless I'm missing something, potentially to do with clipping?).
Why is the API to create CanvasGradients not static?

Comment: You have it almost right. Any one canvas has one-and-only-one context. So if you do multiple `canvas.getContext` you are really repeatedly getting the same context. Gradients are objects that are separate from any particular canvas. You can apply the same gradient across different canvas elements. But yes, you must use a (any) canvas context to create a gradient object.

Comment: Why provide the ability to create a gradient or pattern without a context to use it on. API code is not free, It has a memory cost and there is no reason to instantiate it if it is not needed.